# python: Merge sort not working as intended?

Tags: python, algorithm, mergesort

I am a newcomer to python3 and am trying out the merge sort algorithm as written in the book 'Introduction to Algorithms'. I have the following code which is working properly half way through but failing towards the end for some reason. I tried putting some basic debugging statements before and after calling the `merge()` function. My guess is that it has something to do with the **indices** marking the beginning and end of the subarrays but I cannot figure out exactly what. I tested out the function `merge()` separately on a wide variety of lists to make sure it was working properly before using it within `mergesort()`

```py
from math import inf
from random import randint

def merge(A, p, q, r): 
    L = A[p:q+1]
    R = A[q+1:r+1]
    L.append(inf)
    R.append(inf)
    i = 0
    while L[0] is not inf or R[0] is not inf:
        if L[0] < R[0]:
            A[i] = L.pop(0)
        else:
            A[i] = R.pop(0)
        i += 1

def mergesort(A, p, r):
    if p < r:
        q = (p+r)//2
        mergesort(A, p, q)
        mergesort(A, q+1, r)
        print('merging:', A[p:q+1], 'and', A[q+1:r+1])
        merge(A, p, q, r)
        print('after merging:', A[p:r+1])
     
z =[randint(-100, 100) for x in range(5)]
print('before:', z)
mergesort(z, 0, len(z)-1)
print('after:', z)
```

Here is some output for the initial list `[92, 79, -8, 89, -83]`

```
before: [92, 79, -8, 89, -83]
merging: [92] and [79]
after merging: [79, 92]
merging: [79, 92] and [-8]
after merging: [-8, 79, 92] 
merging: [89] and [-83] <----- okay, alright upto this point...
after merging: [89, -83] <-- ?? goes all wrong from this point...
merging: [-83, 89, 92] and [89, -83]
after merging: [-83, 89, -83, 89, 92]
after: [-83, 89, -83, 89, 92]
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `merge` isn't merging all of `A`, but instead a slice of `A`.  So the first index of `A` needs to be `p`, not `0`.  Just change:

```
    i = 0
```

to:

```
    i = p
```

Here's the whole function:

```
def merge(A, p, q, r): 
    L = A[p:q+1]
    R = A[q+1:r+1]
    L.append(inf)
    R.append(inf)
    i = p
    while L[0] is not inf or R[0] is not inf:
        if L[0] < R[0]:
            A[i] = L.pop(0)
        else:
            A[i] = R.pop(0)
        i += 1
```